# Teaching Tip Hero Content and Tail Visibility - WinUi 2.7 - Bottom variations

Tags: uwp, winui

I have a teaching tip that displays all of the placement variations. The position of the text does not change relative to the image in the most variations, independent of the tail visible or not.

[Teaching tip (left top position) with tail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DArl.png)
[image]

[Teaching tip (left top position) no tail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzeEP.png)
[image]
In bottom positions, the text changes position relative to the image if the tail is visible or not.

[Teaching Tip - right bottom placement - with tail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1dVe.png)
[image]
[Teaching Tip - right bottom placement - no tail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4cHs.png)
[image]
My question is: Is this behavior what is expected for this control?

Comment: We could reproduce this problem, and it looks like  unexpected behavior, please feel  free post this problem in WinUI github [issue box](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues).